# Change property within deeply nested data structure where name matches

Tags: javascript

I have some data structure like so:

```
{
  "category": "Fruits",
  "department": "ABC123",
  "content": {
    "subcategory1": [
      {
        "fruitName": "Apples",
        "inStock": false
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "Pears",
        "inStock": false
      }
    ],
    "subcategory2": [
      {
        "fruitName": "Oranges",
        "inStock": false
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "Lemons",
        "inStock": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to update the "inStock" value based on some input. I have an array like:

`["Pears", "Oranges"]`

For all instances of the properties in that array, I want to update `inStock` to be `true` to end up:

```
{
  "category": "Fruits",
  "department": "ABC123",
  "content": {
    "subcategory1": [
      {
        "fruitName": "Apples",
        "inStock": false
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "Pears",
        "inStock": true
      }
    ],
    "subcategory2": [
      {
        "fruitName": "Oranges",
        "inStock": true
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "Lemons",
        "inStock": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to write some generic function for that, so that I can do something like `const newData = updateStock( oldData );`. However I'm not sure how to start writing this. If I could get some pointers for starting (even if not a solution) I would be very thankful.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: To the OP it's considered polite to upvote and/or accept answers if you found them helpful. Both @NitishNarang and I spent time and effort helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Please always post your attempt in OP so that we get to know how you are approaching..

You can try below approach using `Array.filter` and `Array.forEach`

```js
let data = {
  "category": "Fruits",
  "department": "ABC123",
  "content": {
    "subcategory1": [
      {
        "fruitName": "Apples",
        "inStock": false
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "Pears",
        "inStock": false
      }
    ],
    "subcategory2": [
      {
        "fruitName": "Oranges",
        "inStock": false
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "Lemons",
        "inStock": false
      }
    ]
  }
}

function updateStock(names) {
  Object.values(data.content).flat()
        .filter(d => names.includes(d.fruitName))
        .forEach(d => d.inStock = true)
}

updateStock(['Oranges', 'Pears'])

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this before I saw @NitishNarang's answer, so I'll finish and expand on it a bit.

Start by breaking your problem down into smaller pieces.

First, you want a way to update the `inStock` property on an object. We'll move on to updating multiple objects in a nested data structure later.

I'm going to take a functional approach here. Let's write a higher-order function (a function 'factory', so to speak). When called with a property name and a value, it will return a new function. This new function, when called with an object, will update that object with that property set to the specified value:

```
const updateProperty = (key, value) => obj => {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
};
```

Note that this function can be used for all manner of things. We could make a function to update the key called `material` with the value `chocolate` if we wanted:

```
const renderUseless = updateProperty('material', 'chocolate');
```

Example:

```
const teapot = { material: 'china' };
renderUseless(teapot);
```

Anyway, we can use `updateProperty` to do more useful things, like create convenience functions for marking an item as in or out of stock:

```
const setInStock = updateProperty('inStock', true);
const setOutOfStock = updateProperty('inStock', false);
```

Now, how might we mark a bunch of things as being in stock?

```
const products = [
  {
    fruitName: 'Apples',
    inStock: false
  },
  {
    fruitName: 'Pears',
    inStock: true
  }
];

products.forEach(setInStock);
```

So how might we only run the function for those elements that match a given predicate? Well, we could use `Array.filter`, which when given an array, returns a new array containing only those items that passed a given predicate.

Let's build a function that accepts an array of fruit names, and returns a predicate that returns `true` if its input object has a `fruitName` property that is included in that array, and `false` otherwise:

```
const hasFruitName = names => item =>
  names.includes(item.fruitName);
```

Used in conjunction with `Array.filter`:

```
const products = [
  {
    fruitName: 'Apples',
    inStock: false
  },
  {
    fruitName: 'Pears',
    inStock: true
  }
];

const matchingProducts = products.filter(isFruitName(['Apples']));
```

So we now have a solution for a flat array of items. We just need to deal with your nested data structure. How might we create a flat array of items, given that you have a nested object containing several arrays?

`Object.values(data.content)` will grab the values from the object `data.content`, yielding an array of arrays. To flatten this into a single array, we could use `Array.flat`, but it's not widely-supported yet. Let's make an equivalent portable function:

```
const flattenNestedArray = arr => [].concat.apply([], arr);
```

Now let's make another convenience function:

```
const getItemsFromData = data =>
  flattenNestedArray(Object.values(data.content));
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
const setFruitInStock = (fruitNames, data) =>
  getItemsFromData(data)
    .filter(hasFruitName(fruitNames))
    .forEach(setInStock);
```

This is a bit over-engineered, but hopefully it will illustrate the benefits of starting with small, generic, higher-order functions. You end up with a lot of small, reusable helpers, that grow into slightly more specialised building blocks. Everything is named clearly, and by the time you reach the final implementation it's obvious what's happening at a glance.

Finally, I added `data` as a second parameter so your function is a bit more reusable.

I'll leave refactoring this for purity (i.e. not mutating the input data) as an exercise for the OP :)

Comment: Nice. Explained every piece of the puzzle.